# why >?= and <?= don't work in VC++?

Tags: c++

why `>?=` and `<?=` don't work in VC++?
but they work fine in gcc/g++
like: `a>?=b`;
are they right usages?

Comment: What does it do in gcc? Never saw this before.

Comment: If these are deprecated as bdonlan says, I would expect g++ to print a warning when you use them. I recommend compiling with "-Wall" (warn all, i.e. show all warnings) and trying to write code that produces no warnings. Can someone confirm that g++ does print a warning when you use these operators?

Comment: a>?=b <==> a=MIN(a,b)
I use vim with g++ and compile with "-Wall", but I never see a warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because those are the old [GC++-specific extensions](http://stephane.carrez.free.fr/doc/gcc_6.html#SEC142) for minimum and maximum.

From [6. Extensions to the C++ Language](http://stephane.carrez.free.fr/doc/gcc_6.html#SEC141):

> The GNU compiler provides these extensions to the C++ language (and you can also use most of the C language extensions in your C++ programs). If you want to write code that checks whether these features are available, you can test for the GNU compiler the same way as for C programs: check for a predefined macro `__GNUC__`. You can also use `__GNUG__` to test specifically for GNU C++ (see section 'Predefined Macros' in *The GNU C Preprocessor*).

- [6.1 Minimum and Maximum Operators in C++](http://stephane.carrez.free.fr/doc/gcc_6.html#SEC142) C++ Minimum and maximum operators.
- ...

Instead, you should use `std::min` and `std::max`.

Answer (score 13):

Those operators are non-standard and are deprecated in GCC. They are not even supported in G++ at all anymore. You should use std::min and std::max instead. Be sure to #define NOMINMAX to [disable the window-specific macros](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14540) that conflict with them.