# What does a>?=b mean?

Tags: c++, operators

I found the below code and don't understand what it means:

```
res>?=m[2];
```

Here's the code to where I found it and some context for it.

```
vector<int> m(3);
int s = 0;
... do stuff with m ...
res>?=m[2];
return res;
```

Comment: link are available for registered users only. Can you at leas show what type the res variable has?

Comment: This is definitely on SO somewhere already. You'll probably find the one I'm remembering [in here](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3E%3F%3D). It's an old GCC extension.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is an old GCC extension.

The equivalent of `a >?= b` is `a = max(a,b);`

You may check out [Minimum and Maximum Operators in C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_6.html#SEC116)

> It is very convenient to have operators which return the "minimum" or
>   the "maximum" of two arguments. In GNU C++ (but not in GNU C),
>
> `a <? b`
>
> is the minimum, returning the smaller of the numeric values a and b;
>
> **a >? b**
>
> is the maximum, returning the larger of the numeric values a and b.

[On a side note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234107/why-and-dont-work-in-vc/1234140#1234140):-

> These operators are non-standard and are [deprecated in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html). You should use **[std::min](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)** and **[std::max](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)** instead.

Comment: Note it is deprecated: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html

Comment: @klm123:- min(a,b); will be written as `a <? b`

Comment: we don't need no stinkin' extensions when [operator overloading suffices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18055235/819272)

Answer (score 7):

This is certainly not standard C++. I can *guess* that is shortcut for the assignment + ternary operator, simmilary to assignment + binary operators, like `operator+=` and others:

```
 res = (res > m[2]) ? res : m[2];
```

You can read related here: [Extensions to the C++ Language](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_6.html) :

```
a <? b
is the minimum, returning the smaller of the numeric values a and b;
a >? b
is the maximum, returning the larger of the numeric values a and b.
```